# Why won't my html / css code make a button?

Tags: html, css, image

For some reason the page i've made has stopped showing the image, it's just showing a small broken page icon, even though it showed it before. I haven't changed the name of the image or its location.

I'm also trying to create a button, but it's not showing up

Here's the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>

<link href="design.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="pic">
<img src="C:\Users\A\Desktop\Untitled.jpg" id="pic">
</div>

<div class='banner'>
</div>

<div class="button">
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

and here's the css code:

```
#pic {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    z-index: 1;
    }

.banner {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    }

.button {
    height: 50px;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: #BCD2EE;
    border-color: #6495ED;
    z-index: 3;
    }

Body {
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
}
```

The page just shows the white banner at the top of the page and the grey background, but the image just shows a small broken page icon, and the button isn't being created.

Comment: I forgot to include the </body> and </html> tags in the question, but they are in my code.

Comment: The problem is with `C:\Users\A\Desktop\Untitled.jpg`.

Comment: You probably deleted the image or moved it

Comment: If it's a button, why are you not using `<button>` or at the very least `<a>`? Basic usability rules say you're doing something very wrong here.

Comment: can you post a screenshot? also with inspector open?

Comment: You need to take a step back here and learn the very basics of HTML and most likely CSS. There is a lot of inconsistencies there for such a small amount of code. Using the same ID selector twice, wrapping `banner` in single quotes when the rest of your code is in double quotes, a button as a `<div>` element? Hell no. To answer your question, the path is absolute to your system path, which for security reasons, is not possible in most modern browsers now.

Comment: @haywire, since when do you need to close an `<img>` element, unless you're writing in XHTML (strict)? Edit: the guy deleted his comment. :(

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing a file from your local file system. For security reasons this is not possible, and should never be possible. Upload the image to your server, or move it to the correct folder if you use localhost, and reference the image via an url relative to the domainname.

Comment: Downvoters: Please explain what error I made. After reading the question again, the problem seems to me that OP doesn't understand how the browser fetches external resources. I see no other reason why this image wouldn't show.

Answer (score -2):

You're using a absolute address to the image, my bet is that you either moved the file or renamed it, or even deleted it. Just make sure the path is correct and it should work.

By the way, the `<title>` tag should go inside the `<head>`.

Comment: But it's also the answer. The markup itself is fine, except for the noted errors.

Comment: As long as the user keeps using `C:\...\\` as the reference it will usually not work. It might work if you double click a file in your file system (the file:// protocol), but the last time I tested, even making a two page website with such file system links will not work, because as soon as you navigate the browser will refuse to load the reference.

Comment: I've never had problem with `file://` links, as long as the page is also accessed with `file://`. It will never work if you have mismatched protocols, it would be a absurd hole in security.